# IE pop up 'Syntax Error' when JSONP gets no response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

Current application has to retrieve information from another application, and this other application is not required to be active to respond the `JSONP` request so the initiate requester will pop up an alert message about it.

```
function jsonRequest(requestURL, errorMsg){
    var err = "";
    var requestData= {param1: value1, param2: value2};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        data: requestData,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCb',
        url: requestURL,
        timeout: 20000,
        dataType: 'jsonp', /* this trigger the syntax error window by IE*/
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.hasError != null){
                error = data.error;
                alert(error);
            }else{
                //.... logic to output valid values
            } // closing } is not missing..duh
        },//success
        error:function(x, timeout, m) {
            alert(errorMsg);
        }
    });

    return err;
}
```

so then there are three possible scenarios:

1. JSONP request receives valid data from the other application
2. JSONP request receives empty data from the other application
3. JSONP request gets no response(the other application is not active)

So far so good until testing on IE. The problem is when it comes to `scenario 3` then IE pop up its classic `Syntax Error`, after click 'close' then the alert message in $.ajax `error:{..}` shows up

```
Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI:.......
```

[image: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error]

IE debug tool is pretty lame so it wont allow me to go any details. After I check javascript/jsp code line by line I found the cause of the issue:

In Scenario 3, once I change **`dataType: "jsonp"` to `dataType: "json"`** in the javascript code, then the error no more pop up, but of course the whole ajax request gonna fail. I cannot find out what returns to IE by the debugging tool, when the other application is inactive.

I wonder if there is any effective way to let IE to tolerate `JSONP` or any method to debug where is the cause of the issue.

Comment: which version of internet explorer?

Comment: @Jaromanda X I use IE9, but same problem applies to all 7-8-9 in the compatible mode in developer tool...

Comment: I ask because you say the dev tools are lame. ie11 tools have some functionality that is superior to fx and chrome. can't help you though, I update my windows regularly

Comment: @Jaromanda X for the worth of 4 hours in my life sir, I am going to upgrade to IE11 !!! duh....

Comment: I never suggested you should do anything, so lose the "duh", madam

Comment: @Jaromanda X NP sir, I will take any advice to fix this issue :-) and I appreciate the advice. Actually now I just finish the upgrade and reboot, but the developer tool just failed to show up, it looks the IE7 may not work properly on Win7/64 bit https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3b9dbf66-ee95-4709-9f1a-db740df9c682/ie-11-developer-tools-not-responding-on-win7-x64?forum=ieitprocurrentver. Another good news is that I find that Script Error stop showing up in IE 11, so I think I would head back to IE10. Again thanks very much for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours desperately debugging, finally the fix to this issue emerged:

Just put this setting in ajax code and then the script error never pop up:

```
crossDomain: true,
```

so that

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: aUrl,
    async: true,
    data: urlData,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback',
    crossDomain: true, /***** the life saver ****/
    timeout: 20000,
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(json) {
        if(json.hasError != null && json.hasError == "true"){
            error = json.error;
            alert(error);
        }else{
            //.... logic to output valid values
        } 

    },//success
    error:function(x, tm, m) {
        alert(timeoutErr);
    }
});
```

works just fine

Answer (score 1):

The fact that IE9 works in any scenario with your code is a testament to the sheer incompetence of the microsoft programmers that created the javascript engine for that dinosaur

/rant - Solution to your problem follows: look for `// you forgot this closing brace`

```
function activateManifestJson(aUrl, code, timeoutErr){
    var error = "";

    // RESTful request data
    var urlData = {param1: value1, param2: value2};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: aUrl,
        async: true,
        data: urlData,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 20000,
        dataType: 'jsonp', /* this trigger the syntax error window by IE*/
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.hasError != null && json.hasError == "true"){
                error = json.error;
                alert(error);
            }else{
                //.... logic to output valid values
            // *******************************************
            } // you forgot this closing brace
        // ***********************************************
        },//success
        error:function(x, tm, m) {
            alert(timeoutErr);
        }
    });

    return error;
}
```

Comment: thanks you for the inspection and help me find out an error. It's my bad to remove that closing `}` when copy/paste/edit code in SO but my actual source code DOES have that `}`